# ssh_options parsing fails in capistrano3

Tags: ssh, capistrano, capistrano3

```
cap --version
Capistrano Version: 3.3.5 (Rake Version: 10.4.2)
```

ssh_options is not recognized by the latest cap

```
ssh_options[:keys] = ["#{ENV['HOME']}/.ssh/dev.pem"], forward_agent: true

cap --trace development deploy
cap aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method `ssh_options' for main:Object
```

Forward agent is not recognized by the latest cap

```
ssh_options[:keys] = ["#{ENV['HOME']}/.ssh/dev.pem"], forward_agent: true

cap --trace development deploy
cap aborted!
SyntaxError: config/deploy.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
...dev.pem"], forward_agent: true
...                               ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ssh_options is not a valid Hash.

It should be sth like this:

```
ssh_options = {keys: ["#{ENV['HOME']}/.ssh/dev.pem"], forward_agent: true}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set :ssh_options, {
    keys: %w(/path/to/key),
    forward_agent: false,
    auth_methods: %w(password)
}
```